# Ordenar arreglo de objetos por nombre de columna en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente arreglo de objetos, el cual quisiera ordenar por nombre, o por cualquier otra columna y tengo la siguiente función,
pero no sirve muy bien

```
var array = [
    [
{Nombre: "ALBANIA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "BARRANCAS", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "EL PRADO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "OLAYA HERRERA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "METROPOLITANO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "GRAN BOULEVARD", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "EL RODADERO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "CENTRO COMERCIAL UNICO BARRANQUILLA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SAO 93", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SAN FRANCISCO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "FONSECA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "EL VIVERO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "CALLE 76", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "GRANCENTRO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "RIOHACHA CENTRO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "CARRERA 43", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "PALMA REAL", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "BANCA PERSONAL BARRANQUILLA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "MURILLO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SMART OFFICE", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "BAHIA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SANTA MARTA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SOLEDAD", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "CENTRO COMERCIAL BUENAVISTA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "GREEN TOWERS", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"}
    ]
];

var newArray = [];
array.forEach(elemento => {
    newArray.push(elemento.sort((a, b) => a.Nombre.localeCompare(b.Nombre) ? -1 : a.Nombre.localeCompare(b.Nombre) ? 1 : 0));
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: tienes un error en el codigo no se ordena porque estas haciendo `newArray.push(elemento.sort...` es decir estas agregando el mismo orden que recorre el forEach, puedes usar solo el sort y te devolvera el resultado deseado

Comment: @JackNavaRow Es un array de arrays...

Comment: @PabloLozano usar [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/flatMap)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por pasos:

Ordenar un array es sencillo, sólo necesitas pasar al método `sort()` una función de ordenación del tipo (en pseudocódigo):

```
function compare(obj1, obj1) {
  if (obj1 > obj2) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (obj1 < obj2) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0; //iguales
}
```

Pero lo que quieres es añadir un tercer parámetro que es el tipo de ordenación:

```
function compare(attr, obj1, obj1) {
  if (obj1[attr] > obj2[attr]) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (obj1[attr] < obj2[attr]) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0; //iguales
}
```

Pero esto no funcionaría porque no cumple la interfaz que pide el método `sort`, así que podemos usar [*currificación*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currificaci%C3%B3n):

```
function generaComparador(attr) {
  return function (a,b) {
     return compare(attr,a,b);
  }
}
```

Sumando todo esto nos quedaría:

```js
var array = [
  {Nombre: "ALBANIA", Ejecutado: "2.0", Meta: "0"},
  {Nombre: "BARRANCAS", Ejecutado: "1.0", Meta: "1"},
  {Nombre: "EL PRADO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "4"},
  {Nombre: "OLAYA HERRERA", Ejecutado: "3.0", Meta: "2"},
  {Nombre: "METROPOLITANO", Ejecutado: "0.5", Meta: "3"}
];

function compare(attr, obj1, obj2) {
   return obj1[attr].localeCompare(obj2[attr]);
}

function generaComparador(attr) {
  return function (a,b) {
     return compare(attr,a,b);
  }
}

console.log('Por nombre:', array.sort(generaComparador('Nombre')));
console.log('Por Ejecutado', array.sort(generaComparador('Ejecutado')));
```

Comment: Súper, muchas gracias aunque en el valor de ejecutado con valores como estos:{Nombre: "T OCCIDENTE", Ejecutado: "$ 170.400.000", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "6 und"} {Nombre: "T NORTE", Ejecutado: "$ 33.500.000", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "7 und"} {Nombre: "T BOGOTA", Ejecutado: "$ 750.600.000", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "23 und"} {Nombre: "T CENTRO", Ejecutado: "$ 86.450.000", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "6 und"} No funciona bien, sabes cómo podría hacerlo ?

Answer (score 2):

Vero que guardaste un array de 25 valores dentro de otro array.
Primero debes quitar de ahi:
Ejemplo:

```
arreglo = array[0]
```

Ahora ejecuta la función sort al array llamado **arreglo**, de la siguiente forma:

```
arreglo.sort(function (a, b){
if ( a.Nombre < b.Nombre )
return -1;
if ( a.Nombre > b.Nombre )
  return 1;
return 0;
```

})

El array **arreglo** ahora ya se encuentra ordenado por nombe, favor si podes probar.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción rápida para poder ordenar colecciones, es usando una librería llamada [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15).
El método [`sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy) permite pasarle la colección y el nombre del elemento por el cual quieras iterar

```js
var array = [
{Nombre: "ALBANIA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "BARRANCAS", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "EL PRADO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "OLAYA HERRERA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "METROPOLITANO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "GRAN BOULEVARD", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "EL RODADERO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "CENTRO COMERCIAL UNICO BARRANQUILLA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SAO 93", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SAN FRANCISCO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "100", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "FONSECA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "EL VIVERO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "CALLE 76", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "GRANCENTRO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "RIOHACHA CENTRO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "CARRERA 43", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "PALMA REAL", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "BANCA PERSONAL BARRANQUILLA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "MURILLO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SMART OFFICE", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "BAHIA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SANTA MARTA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SOLEDAD", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "CENTRO COMERCIAL BUENAVISTA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "GREEN TOWERS", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"}
];

var array_ordenado = _.sortBy(array, ['Nombre']);

console.log(array_ordenado)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

para hacer eso yo usaría el siguiente código:

```
var x = "Nombre";
var ascendente = true;

if(ascendente)
{
    array.sort(function(a,b) {return (isNaN(a) && isNaN(b))?((a[x] > b[x]) ? 1 : ((b[x] > a[x]) ? -1 : 0)):(a - b);} );
}
else
{
    array.sort(function(a,b) {return (isNaN(a) && isNaN(b))?((a[x] < b[x]) ? 1 : ((b[x] < a[x]) ? -1 : 0)):(b - a);} );
}
```

siendo la variable `x` el nombre de la propiedad por la cuál ordenar. y la variable `ascendente` la que te va a permitir ordenar de forma ascendente si es `true` y descendente si es `false`.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
var array = [
    [
{Nombre: "ALBANIA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "BARRANCAS", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "EL PRADO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "OLAYA HERRERA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "METROPOLITANO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "GRAN BOULEVARD", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "EL RODADERO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "CENTRO COMERCIAL UNICO BARRANQUILLA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SAO 93", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SAN FRANCISCO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "FONSECA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "EL VIVERO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "CALLE 76", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "GRANCENTRO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "RIOHACHA CENTRO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "CARRERA 43", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "PALMA REAL", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "BANCA PERSONAL BARRANQUILLA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "MURILLO", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SMART OFFICE", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "BAHIA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SANTA MARTA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "SOLEDAD", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "CENTRO COMERCIAL BUENAVISTA", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"},
{Nombre: "GREEN TOWERS", Ejecutado: "0.0", Meta: "0", Cumplimiento: "0.00%", Fábrica: "0 und"}
    ]
];

let newArray = array[0].sort((a, b)=> a.Nombre.localeCompare(b.Nombre) );

//console.table(newArray)
console.log(newArray)
```