# ordenar arreglo node js

Tags: array, nodejs

Hola soy nuevo en esto y estoy tratando de resolver este ejercicio de nodejs pero la verdad que no me resulta.
lo que necesito es hacer que me ordene los datos por rut  y me imprima el ID del arreglo

intente usar el método sort pero no hay caso :(

```
function clienteordenadoporID() {
 
  return clientes.sort((rut) => rut.id);
};
```

me devuelve esto

```
PS C:\Users\Victor\Downloads> node .\test.js
[
  { id: 1, rut: '167123217', nombre: 'MIGUEL ANGEL CARRENO CACES' },
  { id: 2, rut: '17930001k', nombre: 'VICTOR EDUARDO CARRENO CACES' },
  { id: 3, rut: '94884519', nombre: 'LUISA ANDREA CARRENO CACES' },
  { id: 4, rut: '139059925', nombre: 'JOSE MIGUEL CARRENO CACES' }
]
PS C:\Users\Victor\Downloads>
```

el codigo completo es

```
const clientes = [
  { id: 1, rut: '167123217', nombre: 'MIGUEL ANGEL CARRENO CACES'},
  { id: 2, rut: '17930001k', nombre: 'VICTOR EDUARDO CARRENO CACES'},
  { id: 3, rut: '94884519', nombre: 'LUISA ANDREA CARRENO CACES'},
  { id: 4, rut: '139059925', nombre: 'JOSE MIGUEL CARRENO CACES'}
];

const cuentas = [
  
  { clienteId: 1, financieraId: 3, balance: 855 },
 { clienteId: 2, financieraId: 2, balance: 654 },
  { clienteId: 3, financieraId: 1, balance: 993 },
  { clienteId: 3, financieraId: 3, balance: 576 },
  { clienteId: 2, financieraId: 3, balance: 25252 },
  { clienteId: 4, financieraId: 3, balance: 552 },
  { clienteId: 1, financieraId: 2, balance: 1600 },
  { clienteId: 2, financieraId: 3, balance: 522 },
  { clienteId: 3, financieraId: 2, balance: 252 },
  { clienteId: 3, financieraId: 1, balance: 250 },
  { clienteId: 4, financieraId: 3, balance: 556 },
  { clienteId: 2, financieraId: 1, balance: 25525 },
  { clienteId: 1, financieraId: 3, balance: 2422 },
  { clienteId: 2, financieraId: 2, balance: 525 }
]
const financiera = [
  { id: 1, fina: 'SANTANDER' },
  { id: 2, fina: 'CHILE' },
  { id: 3, fina: 'BBVA' },
  { id: 4, fina: 'ESTADO' }
];

function clienteordenadoporID() {
 
  return clientes.sort((rut) => rut.id);
};



console.log(clienteordenadoporID());
```

agradeciendo vuestra ayuda amigos

Comment: hola , capaz te sirva algo de aca https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317542/ordenar-arreglo-de-objetos-por-nombre-de-columna-en-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [String.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/localeCompare) para sortear dependiendo del orden lexicográfico.

> El método localeCompare() devuelve un número que indica si la cadena
> de caracteres actual es anterior, posterior o igual a la cadena pasada
> como parámetro, en orden lexicográfico.

Aplícalo sobre el índice que quieras hacer la comparación

```js
const clientes = [
  { id: 1, rut: '167123217', nombre: 'MIGUEL ANGEL CARRENO CACES'},
  { id: 2, rut: '17930001k', nombre: 'VICTOR EDUARDO CARRENO CACES'},
  { id: 3, rut: '94884519', nombre: 'LUISA ANDREA CARRENO CACES'},
  { id: 4, rut: '139059925', nombre: 'JOSE MIGUEL CARRENO CACES'}
];


clientes.sort( (a,b) => a.rut.localeCompare( b.rut ) );

console.log( clientes );
```